# N queens on a NxN chessboard

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int n=4;
int GetQueenSettings(int board[4][4],int currentRow,int n)
{
    //decide when the recursion stops
    if(currentRow==n)
        return 1; //successful setting
    //otherwise we set column by column in this row and continue
    int TotalSettingCount=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        //make sure it can be set (it is unset at that moment)
        if(board[currentRow][i]==0)
        {
            board[currentRow][i]==1+currentRow;
            //use row related info for settings
            //now set invalid positions for remaining rows
            setInvalid(board,currentRow,n,i);
            //recover after this before trying the next
            TotalSettingCount += GetQueenSettings(board,currentRow+1,n);
            board[currentRow][i]=0;
            RecoverBoard(board,currentRow,n);
        }
    }
    return TotalSettingCount;
}

void setInvalid(int board[4][4],int currentRow,int n,int i)
{
    //vertical and diagonal elements
    for(int row=currentRow+1;row<n;row++) //start from the next line
    {
        //firstly make sure board can be set
        if(board[row][i]==0)//vertical position
            board[row][i]=-(1+currentRow);
        //now check diagonal
        int rowGap=row-currentRow;
        if(i-rowGap>=0 && board[row][i-rowGap]==0)
        {
            //left bottom diagonal position
            board[row][i-rowGap]=-(1+currentRow);
        }
        if(i+rowGap<n && board[row][i+rowGap]==0)
        {
            //bottom right diagonal position
            board[row][i+rowGap]=-(1+currentRow);
        }

    }
}

void RecoverBoard(int board[4][4],int currentRow,int n)
{
    //recover is to check all remaining rows if index is higher than current row(setters)
    //OR less than -currentRow(invalids)!
    for(int row=currentRow+1;row<n;row++)
    {
        for(int col=0;col<n;col++)
        {
            if(board[row][col]>currentRow || board[row][col]< -currentRow)
                board[row][col]=0;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{

    int board[n][n];
    printf("Number of settings:-> %d",GetQueenSettings(board,0,n));

    return 0;
}
```

There are N queeens placed on a NxN chessboard without interfering with each other. when i run this code i get the answer as zero instead of 2 . also i cant figure out a way of passing array board to functions with variable size(size will be given by user).What am i doing wrong?!

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and you will see that you have a comparison instead of an assignment here `board[currentRow][i]==1+currentRow;`.

Comment: yeah i changed that .still no luck . still output is zero .

Comment: I dont think you need to store the whole board as it guaranteed that there is only one queen per row. you could store the queens col position into a 1 dimension array of size N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize your `board`. As is, you start with a board full of garbage values. You are using a variable-length array as board. Such arrays cannot be initialized, so you have to set the board to all zero with a loop or with `memset` from `<string.h>`:

```
int board[n][n];

memset(board, 0, sizeof(board));
```

You can pass variable-length arrays to functions when the dimensions are passed in as earlier arguments, for example:

```
int GetQueenSettings(int n, int board[n][n], int currentRow) { ... }
```

Also fix the `=`/`==` switch in `setInvalid`:

```
    if (board[row][i] == 0)
        board[row][i] = -(1 + currentRow);
```

Finally make sure that all functions have proper prototypes when they are called.

Answer (score 0):

A loooooooong time ago I developed an algorithm like the one you have, maybe it can help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

long Solutions;

void AllocBoard(int *** Board, int Queens)
    {
    int i;

    *Board = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * Queens);

    for(i = 0; i < Queens; i++)
        {
        (*Board)[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * Queens);
        memset((*Board)[i], 0, sizeof(int) * Queens);
        }
    }

void DeallocBoard(int *** Board, int Queens)
    {
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < Queens; i++)
        free((*Board)[i]);

    free(*Board);
    }

void SavePosition(int *** Board, int Queens, int Col, int Row, int Inc)
    {
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < Queens; i++)
        {
        if((*Board)[Col][i] >= 0) (*Board)[Col][i] += Inc;
        if((*Board)[i][Row] >= 0) (*Board)[i][Row] += Inc;
        }

    for(i = Col, j = Row; j < Queens && i < Queens; i++, j++)
        if((*Board)[i][j] >= 0) (*Board)[i][j] += Inc;

    for(i = Col, j = Row; j >= 0 && i >= Col; i--, j--)
        if((*Board)[i][j] >= 0) (*Board)[Col][j] += Inc;

    for(i = Col, j = Row; j >= 0 && i < Queens; i++, j--)
        if((*Board)[i][j] >= 0) (*Board)[i][j] += Inc;

    for(i = Col, j = Row; j < Queens && i >= Col; i--, j++)
        if((*Board)[i][j] >= 0) (*Board)[i][j] += Inc;
    }

void FindSolutions(int *** Board, int Queens, int Col)
    {
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < Queens; i++)
        {
        if((*Board)[Col][i] != 0) continue;

        (*Board)[Col][i] = -1;
        if(Col + 1 == Queens)
            Solutions++;
        else
            {
            SavePosition(Board, Queens, Col, i, 1);
            FindSolutions(Board, Queens, Col + 1);
            SavePosition(Board, Queens, Col, i, -1);
            }

        (*Board)[Col][i] = 0;
        }
    }

void main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
    int Queens, ** Board = NULL;
    clock_t Start, End;

    clrscr();
    if(argc < 2)
        Queens = 8;
    else
        Queens = atoi(argv[1]);

    Solutions = 0;

    Start = clock();
    AllocBoard(&Board, Queens);
    FindSolutions(&Board, Queens, 0);
    DeallocBoard(&Board, Queens);
    End = clock();

    printf("Solutions %ld\n", Solutions);
    printf("Estimated time: %f", (End - Start) / CLK_TCK);
    getch();
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Asking "why it doesn't work" about short and simple programs is not very well. Try debug it yourself with any debugger or simply using printing in important places/on each step. Actually, C has no arrays, instead it has pointers. You can work with them very alike, that is why all you need is to change `int board[4][4]` to `int **board` and add one argument: `int N`(count of cells) and that's all. All your other code shouldn't be changed.